# Angular, put string in url in ng-repeat (for img link)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically call pictures inside an ng-repeat. My first attempt was to add a key/value of 'img' to my JSON object I'm pulling and and try to drop it to the inside of he url. This does not seem to work. Here is what I mean :

```
     <div ng-repeat="item in marketItemsTest | filter:searchPrivate>    
                    <img src="assets/images/" + item.name + ".jpg" alt="img01"/>
```

Am I not escaping this correctly? Or maybe it cannot be done this way. I am just storing the name of the jpg, should I store more than that?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/{{item.name}}.jpg"/>
```

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) for ngSrc explicitly advise against creating a `src` string like you are doing.

Plus in the original your were missing the braces `{{item.name}}` which was why it wasn't working at all. It should have been:

```
<img src="assets/images/{{item.name}}.jpg"/>
```

But doing that will cause the browser to first try to load from `assets/images/{{item.name}}.jpg`